# How to measure network traffic round trip delays and jitter

Tags: networking, network-monitoring, network-traffic

I am hoping someone may point me in the direction. I would like generate some network traffic between two endpoints and measure the delay, jitter and packet loss along the path. Could some please point me in the right direction as to what traffic generator to deploy and how to get the measurements. I am fairly new to networking please forgive such a trivial request.

Answer (score 2):

iperf is a great tool and can do everything you are asking for and more, if you can install it on both hosts (client and server).

Here is a little [guide](http://openmaniak.com/iperf.php) on using it.